# Enable Edit Menu for NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, edit, copy-paste

I'm new in cocoa but with some experience with Cococa-Touch. As I am developing a OSX Lion app that uses tables (NSTableView and NSOutlineView), I am having troubles trying to add copy-paste features to tables.

I have no problems with drag-n-drop features that I have coded in table view controllers. But I cannot make edit menu options (copy and paste) enable.

I did read apple documents, but I'm missing something. I can't make it work. Can you please guide me with the first steps to enable that edit menu options and attend them from table view's controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, so I answer my own question.

I have subclassed NSTableView and NSOutlineView and, in the new class, included the methods: -validateUserInterfaceItem: , copy: and so on. I was erroneously expecting to receive actions in Table Delegates.